# Trying to get package.el to work on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, package

My ultimate goal is to get Clojure/Swank/Slime running through Emacs on Mac OS X. To try and get there I'm installing various modes into Emacs (I'm trying both Aquamacs and EMacsforMacOsx). I've looked at several posts on here and elsewhere on the web and the current advice seems to be to use ELPA.

I've grabbed what I think is the latest package.el (for Emacs 23.x) from [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob_plain/1a0a666f941c99882093d7bd08ced15033bc3f0c:/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el) and I can use this to install clojure-mode. As I like to know that things are working correctly I've also tried to delete packages that I've installed. When I do this (I use package-list-packages, D to delete, X to execute) I get the following error:

`` condition-case: Wrong type argument: stringp, #[(directory &optional recursive) 
...
...
[directory handler recursive delete-by-moving-to-trash directory-files-no-dot-files-regexp 
directory-file-name expand-file-name find-file-name-handler delete-directory directory-files 
...] 7 1863281 (let ((dir (expand-file-name (read-file-name "Delete directory: " default-
directory default-directory nil nil)))) (list dir (if (directory-files dir nil directory-files-no-dot-files-regexp) (y-or-n-p (format "Directory `%s' is not empty, really delete? " dir)) nil)))] ``

where the ...s are a bunch of hex characters

This is happening on both versions of Emacs I've tried.

Am I using the correct version of package.el.

If so, what can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like an incompatibility between the `package.el` you're using and the surrounding Emacs. Aquamacs comes bundled with `package.el`, so you probably shouldn't use your own version with that. I use a nightly build from EmacsForMacOSX, which also has a built-in `package.el`. You appear to have grabbed a reasonable version of the package, but you'll need to give more info to help diagnose what's wrong. e.g. which exact Emacs versions you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In my .emacs file if I do (require 'package) without including my package.el in the load path then I get "File error: Cannot open load file, package" I've looked in both Emacs.app and Aquamacs.app and can't see package.el, where would they be located? As for versions I'm using 23.3 (9.0) of EmacsForMac and 2.4 of Aquamacs

Comment: `package.el` is only included in Emacs 24 (meaning the nightly builds, not the 23.x series).  I double-checked the Aquamacs situation, and I was mistaken; package.el isn't bundled with it.  Now that I think about it, I think I might have seen a similar error in Emacs 24 when upgrading outdated packages, during which package.el prompts to delete the obsolete versions.  I'll keep an eye out for it happening again, but in the meantime, you can just delete the offending package directory by hand or from dired.

Comment: for any remaining emacs-23 users:  the new URL for the last version of package.el compatible with emacs-23 is:  <http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob_plain;hb=ba08b24186711eaeb3748f3d1f23e2c2d9ed0d09;f=lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the right `package.el` (but see sanityinc's comment), load that source file explicitly `(load-file "..../package.el")`, then do `M-x debug-on-entry package-delete`. That will put you in the debugger when you invoke that function (which seems to be where there error is raised).  Use `d' to step or`c' to continue, in the debugger, to follow the evaluation. Keep the source code displayed in a separate buffer so you can follow more easily.

What seems to be happening is that in the call `(delete-directory dir t t)` the `DIR` arg is not a string, which would mean that `package--dir` did not return a directory (string).

Also, it looks like the args for your version of `delete-directory` are `(directory &optional recursive)`.  At least in the version of `package.el` in Emacs 24, `delete-directory is actually called here with 3 args. But you didn't get a wrong-number-of-args error, so maybe your versions are different.

Anyway, use the debugger to try to find what went wrong. It seems likely that, as sanityinc suggested, you have a mismatch of code versions.

Comment: Just to try this out I'm trying to delete a color-them package (color-theme-actress) that is at version 0.1.0. If I break at package-delete, the call I see looks like:package-delete("color-theme-actress" #("0.1.0" 0 5 (font-lock-face font-lock-comment-face))) which I'm guessing is wrong. I assume the font-lock stuff should not be there

Comment: No, that is not indicative of a problem. The syntax `#("...")` represents a Lisp string (in this case the string "0.1.0") that has Emacs text properties applied to it (in this case, text property `font-lock-face` with value `font-lock-comment-face`).

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the input. Rather than waste more time on this I've moved to Emacs 24 which gives me what I need. Thanks again,

Kevin